# problems with android ndk-gdb

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have two android projects: a library project which implements an SDK and a test application which is a regular android app (and uses the sdk jar). The SDK project contains native code which I call using JNI.
I am trying to enable debugging my JNI native code in eclipse. I installed ndk r7. I followed this tutorial:
http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

I am stuck when trying to run ndk-gdb. This is what I get when running it:

```
$ ndk-gdb --adb=/cygdrive/C/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe --verbose  
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/build/core/ndk-common.sh: eval: line 538: syntax error near unexpected token `('  
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/build/core/ndk-common.sh: eval: line 538: `ADB_CMD=/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb'  
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/build/core/ndk-common.sh: line 538: warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause future versions of the shell to abort as Posix requires  
Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7  
Using specific adb command: /cygdrive/C/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe  
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29  
Using final ADB command: '/cygdrive/C/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe'  
Using auto-detected project path: .  
Found package name: com.nuance.vbserver  
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi armeabi-v7a  
Device API Level: 10  
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi  
Compatible device ABI: armeabi-v7a  
Found debuggable flag: true  
ERROR: Non-debuggable application installed on the target device.  
       Please re-install the debuggable version!
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of your app was built in release mode without debug symbols. Try rebuilding in debug mode. Without your makefile, it's hard to explain exactly how to do this, but [this webpage](http://betelco.blogspot.com/2010/01/buildingdebugging-android-native-c.html) has some good step by step instructions for how to set it up.

Comment: I am trying to set it up via eclipse so I can run my java code and my native code in the same env. I am also building via the sequoya plugin in eclipse. If you'll point me to the make file you need I'll paste it here.

Comment: BTW, this happened after I deleted the awk tool that comes with the NDK. It broke the eclpise build capability so I restored it. Now I get  ABIs targetted by application: Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !

Comment: You were right. I manually deleted all the object files and recompiled and it worked.

Comment: ... This was when I compiled from the command line. When I compile it from eclipse the problem returns.

Comment: What if I'm using proprietary shared objects that simply don't have debug symbols, but my own library _does_? Is there _any_ way around this? I'm about ready to give up on native Android development entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use "ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1" command to compile your code

Comment: and make sure android:debuggable="true" is in your application tag within AndroidManifest.xml